# How to fix 404 Error on Github pages? [github]

Tags: github, github-pages

[here](https://github.com/okrecommendation9394/shelter) is my github repository. I uploaded html and css files on main branch, then created gh-pages branch and made a pull-request. Link still doesn't work. When I try to open page it gives me 404 File not found. Any solutions ?[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE57l.png)

Comment: Did you wait long enough? Looks like it's working just fine: https://okrecommendation9394.github.io/shelter/